# Carrierwave: Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model'

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, carrierwave

I am receiving this error:

```
Can't resolve image into URL: undefined method `to_model' for #<PortfolioUploader:0x007fd1538a2a60>
Did you mean?  to_xml
```

I am using carrierwave rails and when I check my form looks like this:

```
  <% @portfolios.each do |portfolio_item| %>
  <p><%= portfolio_item.title %> </p>
  <p><%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %> </p>
  <p><%= portfolio_item.body %> </p>
  <p><%= link_to "Edit", edit_portfolio_path(portfolio_item) if logged_in?(:site_admin)%></p>
  <p><%= link_to "Delete", portfolio_path(portfolio_item), method: :delete, data: { confirm: 'Are you sure?' } if logged_in?(:site_admin)%></p>
  <% end %>
```

And on my form:

```
<%= render 'form', portfolio: @portfolio %>




 <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :main_image %>
  </div>

  <div class="field">
    <%= f.file_field :thumb_image %>
 </div>
```

On my model I put the ff:

```
  mount_uploader :thumb_image, PortfolioUploader
  mount_uploader :main_image, PortfolioUploader
```

Any idea what am I missing?

Comment: Which line of the code causes the error?

Answer (score 13):

If you just upgraded to Rails 5.2, the behaviour of `image_tag` changed between Rails 5.1 and 5.2.

In Rails 5.1, you could pass an uploader object, like in the question asked:

```
# Rails 5.1
image_tag(portfolio_item.thumb_image)
```

But in Rails 5.2, `image_tag` now expects a url:

```
# Rails 5.2
image_tag(portfolio_item.thumb_image_url)
```

Answer (score 9):

I suppose it should be

```
<%= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image.url unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue, resolved using an interpolated string of the image url. Instead of

```
= image_tag portfolio_item.thumb_image
```

I used

```
= image_tag "#{portfolio_item.thumb_image}"
```

Answer (score 0):

This should work perfectly for you, even when no image is uploaded:

```
<%= image_tag(portfolio_item.thumb_image_url) if portfolio_item.thumb_image_url %>
```

**Note**: The if statement is to avoid errors when no image is present or has been uploaded.

That's all.

**I hope this helps**

Answer (score -1):

Usually I do in this way

```
<%= image_tag(portfolio_item.thumb_image_url) unless portfolio_item.thumb_image.nil? %>
```